# Edit certain files in multiple directories using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I maintain multiple mail servers that have clear text configuration files in each users folder with the following hierarchy:

```
domain.com
->user1
->user2
anotherdomain.com
->user3
->user4
```

In each user's folder is a file that needs to be edited. Each file needs the first part changed to the following:

```
#!0 __WebmailJunk__
#if allof (spamtest, not address :all :is "From" "") {
#  fileinto "Junk E-mail";
#  stop;
#}
```

changed from:

```
#!1 __WebmailJunk__
if spamtest {
fileinto "Junk E-mail";
stop;
}
```

This is assuming that the file hasn't already been changed.

I think I figured out how to edit the file one by one with the following code:

```
while read line 
do
    CHARACTER=`echo $line | cut -c 1`
    if [[ $CHARACTER == "}" ]] ;
        then
            exit 0
    fi
    sed -i -e 's/^/#/' <filename>
done
```

Haven't figured out how to parse each user directory only one folder deep to edit the file. The servers in question are running CentOS 6.4.

Comment: Where you have the list of the parent dirs? And do they contain only those userX type files only?

Comment: I would run the script from the directory that lists the domains hosted on the mail server and inside each of those folders is each user. The file in question (filter.siv) is located in the user folder. example path: domainname.com/bob.smith/filter.siv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use find to match the user files ?
e.g.

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "user*" -exec script_that_does_text_replace.sh {\} \;
```

where `script_that_does_text_replace.sh` is the code you wrote above.

Comment: find . -maxdepth 3 -name "filter.siv" -exec script.sh {} \; works to find the files and run the script. Just need to get the script working now.

Comment: the {\} is where the `find` result will be placed when executing the command. i.e. if the first file that `find` would find is "test/f1.txt" the command would be `script_that_does_text_replace.sh test/f1.txt`